# How do I disable this behavior of WebStorm with Styled-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webstorm, styled-components

#### Background

I'm new to WebStorm and playing around with it.

I just installed **styled-components** plugin for WebStorm: https://github.com/styled-components/webstorm-styled-components
I get this confusing highlighting which does not disappear.

[image]

[image]

#### Questions

- Are you familiar with this behavior?
- Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this highlighting indicates [language injection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/using-language-injections.html). If you don't like its green background, you can change the color in *Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | General, Code > Injected language fragment settings*, *Background*.

Comment: It worked :)

Do you know why does the editor treat this code as a different language (as a language injectection)?

What is so different with this snippet I shared to the rest of my syntax around? I write Javascript / es6 / jsx / template literals / etc..

Comment: Hmm... strange question. Don't you know what styled components are? it's CSS code inside JavaScript... And language injection is needed to be able to provide completion, validation, etc. of CSS properties inside your tagged template literals

Comment: Maybe I dont know what is `styled-components`, and be greatly happy to learn something new here :)

but when I write styled components with template literals i write javascript, not css. whatever happens to this line of code later  on runtime is not something i need to be informed with, i think...

I wrote a string, and wrapped it with an es6  synatx which is not different behavior from the rest of my code in this React project,
so why here i get a different IDE behavior

Comment: ok. If you don't like getting completion/syntax highlighting for CSS properties inside your javascript, please uninstall styled-components plugin - you just don't need it. And enjoy editing javascript:)

Answer (score 0):

That's normal. If you click outside of your string, the background (color) should disappear. The color only applies if your cursor is within your string. It's just highlighting the whole string for you, so you know that you're working within the string declared within the backticks `

Comment: I wish it was true! this is the obvious behavior,
but even when the cursor is out it still is highlighted

Comment: Sorry then, I really thought that would be the case. Maybe arestart of the IDE would help. Anyways - I've no idea, sorry.